# Two identical AutomationID using xpath python with appium

Tags: python, testing, xpath, automation, appium

In in our mobile app, there are two boxes with the same AutomationId.
For automated testing i need to find the first of the two elements by xpath. 
I tried following code, bt it didn't work:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "xpath=(//[@contentDescription='Cards'])[1]").click()

time.sleep(0.5)
self.assertEqual('Angle x:',
        self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('MovementsTitle').text)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the following way

```
    els = self.driver. find_elements_by_xpath('xpath=(//[@contentDescription='Cards'])')
    els[0].click()
```

Description :

First, get the all identical elements through "find_elements" this will give you as an array of elements then you can perform the actions accordingly

Comment: Great, thank you! Now it's working perfect. Just need to add automated scrolling!

Answer (score 0):

if they have the same id, you can do the following, use the findelements method (yes in plural) as follows:

```
driver.findElementsByAccessibilityID("Cards").get(0).click();
```

just specify the index of the element try 0 or 1.